# Does it make sense to have a non-optional weak reference?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, reference

Consider this code:

```
internal weak var someObj: SomeClass? = TheObject.Exists().Somewhere.obj
```

This seems perfectly reasonable. The reference is weak - that is we have no control over someObj's lifetime - and so at some point the reference may become nil. Even `SomeClass!` could me regarded as acceptable, as long as you are aware of the possible risk.
Now how about this:

```
internal weak var anotherObj: AnotherClass = aDifferent.Source().ofObjects.obj
```

The compiler does not even issue a warning. Weak suggests the reference may point at an object which had been deallocated. On the other hand the non-optional `AnotherClass` type doesn't really allow that. Can such code be justified?

Comment: The compilers complains with error: "'weak' variable should have optional type"

Comment: For some reason didn't happen to me. I will try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler won't allow a non-optional weak.